# Why isn't my mini fridge getting cold?

Tags: electrical, repair, kitchens

I recently got a mini fridge from my neighbor. He said he didn't want it because it wasn't keeping his food cold. I examined it and it is a brand new mini refrigerator in good condition except for the fact that the cooling system isn't working. Its a Black & Decker brand and is probably like 2x2 feet. Is there any way that I can fix this myself, or is it not worth the effort?

Comment: I'm surprised we don't have a good answer on this site yet for troubleshooting a fridge..

Comment: There is no way to answer this question.  You *might* be able to repair it, if you're handy and it's repairable.  It was built, and so it can be rebuilt. The question is, can you rebuild it cheaper than buying a new one?  This is going to depend on what's wrong with it.  Since we don't know your handiness level, or what's wrong with the fridge. It's nearly impossible to answer this question.

Comment: Does the fridge use [absorption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_refrigerator), or [vapor compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor-compression_refrigeration) for cooling?

Comment: @Tester101 - It could also use a thermoelectric (Peltier) cooler.  I've seen numerous mini fridges, especially portable ones, that used those rather than a phase change unit

Answer (score 2):

"...a brand new mini refrigerator in good condition except...". Such a deal. The cooling system in these low cost mini fridges is the main part of the things. It is almost a sure bet that any replacement parts to repair the compressor or evaporator will cost as much or more than a new unit at a high volume retail outlet. I would recommend not even spending the time trying to troubleshoot it. Maybe you may do good in talking your neighbor into taking the unit back so you do not end up with the hassle of disposing of the thing.